# Passing Struct Array to a Thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to pass a whole array of a struct to a thread, where I need to have their index to differentiate the different arrays inside the thread.

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} StructA;

typedef struct {
    StructaA str;
    pthread_mutex_t* mutex;
} Parameters;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int n=3;

main(){

    pthread_t thread;
    StructA str[n];
    Parameters thParam[n];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        thParam[i].str = &str[i];
        thParam[i].mutex = &mutex;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &Thread1, (void*)&thParam))
        exit;
    }

    etc...
}

Thread1(params*){

    Parameters * param[n];
    StructA stra[n];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        ??????????????????
    }
}
```

I have thought about something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<ghostN; i++){
    param[i] = ((Parameters*) params+i);
    stra[i] = param[i];
}
```

but I am just messing more and more the code. What would be the correct way to do this?

Consider that I must do this in order to see each str[n] values (the struct inside the main which I passed to the thread) inside the thread itself.

Comment: what exactly your thread needs from the thParam? do you need all its context available in all threads or you need just the `[i]` part of it in a corresponding thread?  it seems that the latter is more logical.

Comment: `thread` is not an array, `pthread_create(&thread[i],...` is going to scribble on stack memory, that may or may not belong to you.

Comment: `(void*)&thParam` can be just `thParam`.

Comment: @Serge yes I just need the i inside the thread to distinguish each thread data, I actually need that a thread can see another thread (of same type) data.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  I don't think your code can be compiled.  Please post an [mcve].

Comment: @jwdonahue well the code is so long so I basically tried to write out an easier example that shows the problem I'm having

Comment: Yes, that is the goal.  Provide an [mcve].  Once you get that to compile, we can discuss your issue.  So first, work your way through the compiler errors, then post the reduced example.

Comment: To put it another way; if I can't cut, paste and compile your code, why should I bother trying to provide an answer to your question?  Usually, by the time you get part way into your MCVE, you solve your problem on your own.

Comment: IMO, this question needs to be better focused: What did you try? What happened when you tried it? In what way did that fail to meet your expectations?  NOTE: If your "failed expectation" was, "I got this compiler error message, ___________, which I do not understand," then of course it is not necessary for your MCVE to be compilable.

Answer (score 0):

The memory of the main process is shared between all thereads. So, every thread has an ability to access the same variable or
arrays. The only thing which makes sense to pass to a thread startup function is somethign uniquie. Note, you cannot pass anything
to a thread, thread is not a function, but you can pass something to the thread start-up function to keep it on the stack of this
function. Every call to a function allocates stack unique to this function.

So, in your example I would keep the `thParam` array in the global scope to make it accessible by all threads, something like the following

```
Parameters thParam[n];
StructA str[n];

void *startThread(void *arg) {
     long int i = (long int)arg;

     use(thParam[i]);
}

main(){

    pthread_t thread[n];

    for (long int i=0; i<n; i++){
        thParam[i].str = &str[i];
        thParam[i].mutex = &mutex;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, &startThread, (void*)i))
        exit;
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that in the above case all writes to thParam is done before the thread starts. So there is no need to provide any
synchronization here. Also, since all threads access their own portion of the array only, defined by `i`, there is no need to
synchronize either.

You need to pass `i` by value, to avoid synchronization issues. Therefore you'd better have 'long int' to match its size to the size of the void* pointer.

And in your cases the `thread` must be an array as well.